# Repeat same long code many times

Tags: php, include, repeat

I'm doing a workaround to filter results using Cimy User Extra fields (I'm not able to do queries and so). So I created a dropdown form and I'm using the selected fields/values to filter the users to be shown.

Here is the function of the Wordpress Users plugin used to display de users "list"

```
function get_user_listing($curauth) { 
  global $post;
  $concat = wpu_concat_single();
  $homeuni=get_cimyFieldValue($curauth->ID,'homeuni');
  $selectedhomeuni = $_GET['homeunis']; // Key that gets one dropdown value
  $selectedhostuni = $_GET['hostunis']; // Key that gets the other dropdown value

if($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all") {
// Here goes the bunch of repeated code
 }
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all") {
// Here goes the bunch of repeated code again
 }
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all") {
 // Here goes the bunch of repeated code again
}  
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all") {
 // Here goes the bunch of repeated code again
}

  return $html;
}
```

And [here (Pastebin) is the long code to be repeated](http://pastebin.com/tqTSNdDZ). with ", ', \" and $.

I've tried functions, keys and include to call that code, but none of them worked properly. I'm not even sure it can be done this "easy" as I'm trying. I'm no expert at all.

Thank you very much.

Comment: With a function, and judging from the pastebin, an array map.

Comment: what is the error message if you use `include`?

Comment: @mario I will look at it, although it doesn't seem easy at all.

Comment: @bansi If I use include, the page displays the lot of code as many times as users to be shown, and it generates a few divs (the initial part of the pastebin code I guess).

Comment: I'm stupid. I just had to put the "return $html;" inside the {} (where I wrote the "here goes..." and that was it!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put the "return $html;" inside the {} (where I wrote the "here goes..." and that was it!

Now I just have to find a better way to set the possible combinations (I have to add 2 more options, which leaves me with 16 possibilities...)